# Second derivative and point of inflection

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ has a second derivative in $I$ and $c$ is an inner point of $I$ such that $f’’(c) = 0$, then $c$ is a point of inflection.

---

The question is to prove the sentence if it’s true or to show a counterexample it it’s false. The first thing I thought was any constant function, for example $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in I$. $f(x)$ has a second derivative and $f’’(c) = 0$ but c is not a point of inflection since the function is constant.

I don’t know if my argument is valid because I don’t know if all the points of a constant function are points of inflection. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are correct in suggesting a constant function as a counter-example -- by most conventions, it does indeed have no inflection points.

Comment: Write down the definition of a point of inflection and look at your example.

Comment: The definition of a point of inflection that I have seen in class is: $f$ has a point of inflection in $x_0$ if $\exists \rho > 0$ such that $\forall x \in V_{\rho}^*(x_0) \cap I:$ $(x-x_0)(f(x)-f(x_0)-f’(x_0)(x-x_0))$ is non-zero and has a constant sign. Where $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and differentiable at $x_0$. So, for $f(x) = 0$ $\forall x \in I$ the computation above is 0, therefore it would not have a point of inflection at $x_0 = c$. Am I right?

Comment: $f(x)=x^4, x\in(-4,4)$.

Comment: @Riemann I guess what you are trying to say is to check the function you gave with the definition I stated, which resulted with $x^5$ for $x_0 = 0$ which doesn’t have constant sign in $(-4,4)$, then 0 is not an inflection point ?